# Python - Replace a Number in Multiple Files

Tags: python, file, replace, numbers

I'd like to replace a certain number say 3.54 with 3.363 in multiple .inp files and save in place.

This is what I have written so far but I don't know where the problem is !
so I would appreciate it if someone could have a look at this.

```
for i in range(1, 126):
 file = 'C:/inp/' + str(i) +'.inp'
 o2 = open(name=file, readOnly=False)  
 for line in ("file"):
  file.write(line.replace('3.54', '3.363'))
 file.close()
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do it in python and not with something simple, like `sed` and your shell?

Comment: Ah, I missed the "C:" part. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The for loop:

```
for line in ("file"):
```

makes `line` equal to `'f'`, then `'i'`, then `'l'`, then `'e'`.

Try

```
import fileinput
import sys
import re

filenames = ['C:/inp/%d.inp'%i  for i in range(1, 126)]
for line in fileinput.input(filenames, inplace = True,
                            backup = '.bak'):        
    sys.stdout.write(re.sub(r'\b3.54\b', '3.363', line))
```

Note that `line.replace('3.54', '3.363')` is a bit dangerous. It will change `13.54` to `13.363`, for example. To protect against this, use regex.

References to tools used:

- [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) module
- [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (used to defined `filenames`)
- [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) (regex substitution)

Comment: If you had "for line in file(filename).readlines()" there, and wouldn't call your variable file, it would work fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but forgive my ignorance (I am a newbie), how can I use the regexp as my .inp files may as well have those numbers.

Comment: @Esan: I've edited the post to show the use of `re.sub`. What do your lines look like? The regex may need tweeking if for example, the number `3.54` is followed immediately by an letter, not a space or comma...

Comment: Thank you, you are a life saver ! The code worked beautifully !
I checked the input files and it's hardly unlikely that they contain the combination.